# Haskell Pattern Matching Fails on Negative Number

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming, pattern-matching

The Haskell compiler throws an error on the following function:

```
balancedMax :: Int -> Int -> Int
balancedMax -1 _ = -1
balancedMax _ -1 = -1
balancedMax a b = max a b
```

Flipping the sign solves the problem:

```
balancedMax :: Int -> Int -> Int
balancedMax 1 _ = -1
balancedMax _ 1 = -1
balancedMax a b = max a b
```

Why does pattern matching fail on the negatives, and what is a clean workaround?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It fails because it thinks you're trying to re-define the minus operator, because `f -1 = ...` gets parsed as `f - 1 = ...`.

To fix this you just have to add parentheses:

```
balancedMax :: Int -> Int -> Int
balancedMax (-1) _ = -1
balancedMax _ (-1) = -1
balancedMax a b = max a b
```

The same thing happens in expressions. To call `balancedMax` with a negative literal, you would need parentheses as well.

Answer (score 7):

> because `f -1 = ...` gets parsed as `f - 1 = ....`

Which if you don't know, means the same thing as:

```
(-) f 1 = ....
```

which is similar to defining a function like this:

```
somefunc x 1 = x + 1
```

Which happens to be equivalent to defining somefunc() like this:

```
x `somefunc` 1 = x + 1
```

It's just that with (-) you don't have to write the backticks when using it in  **infix** position, i.e. positioned between its two arguments.

The two beginning haskell books I've looked at both warn you early on that the unary - needs to be used with parentheses, e.g. (-3).